# How to deploy multi-region in ocata openstack in juju?

Tags: cloud, openstack, lxd, juju

I am unable to add multi region support for Openstack Ocata, using juju deployment.

I'm following the steps(for Single Region) given in the link: [OpenStack on LXD](https://docs.openstack.org/charm-guide/latest/openstack-on-lxd.html)

For **multi region** I am stuck where to make changes,so that I have master region(maybe region zero) and as well as slave regions(maybe region one and region two), which can be visible on `Openstack dashboard`.
Please guide me how to do the multi region setup.

Comment: Please provide more information like what you have tried so far and where you are stuck at etc .. it will help more whoever tries to answer your question

Comment: @JithinScaria Thanks for the feed, I have made the required changes :)